# How to show this property of $\mathbb{RP}^{n}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-geometry

To prove that:
The $n$-dimensional projective space can be presented as:

> $\mathbb{RP}^n=\bigcup_{i=0}^{n} A^{i}$.

(The intersection of each two $A^{i}$ is empty)،
$A^{i}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{i}$
($A^{0}$ includes only one point).
The definition of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is:
$\mathbb{RP}^n= (\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\})/ \sim$ , $\sim$ is defined as: $x \sim \lambda x$for all $\lambda\in \mathbb R^\times$ and $x\in \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$. $\mathbb R^\times $ is the productive group of scalars $\ne0$ in the field $\mathbb R$.

I'm just a beginner in this field so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which definition of $\mathbb RP^n $ do you use?

Comment: @Paul Frost , $RP^n= (R^{n+1}\{0})/ ~$ ,    ~ is defined as: $x=\lambda*x$ for all $\lambda \inR^{x}$ and $x\inR^{n+1}\{0}$.  $R^{x}$ is the productive group of scalars ≠0 in the field R.

Comment: Do you know that is also the quotient space obtained from $S^n$ by identifying antipodal points?

Comment: @Paul Frost ,  yse I guess , but I would like to see this in an explanation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb RP^n$ is known to be a Hausdorff space (it is even a manifold, but we do not need this fact here). The quotient map $p : \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb RP^n$ restricts to a surjective map $q : S^n \to \mathbb RP^n$. For each $y \in \mathbb RP^n$, $q^{-1}(y)$ is a pair of antipodal points in $S^n$. Since $S^n$ is compact and $\mathbb RP^n$ is Hausdorff, $q$ is closed map and therefore a quotient map.  This gives an alternative description of $\mathbb RP^n$: It is the quotient space obtained from $S^n$ by identifying antipodal points.

The map $q$ is also an open map: If $U \subset S^n$ is open, then $q^{-1}(q(U)) = U \cup (-U)$ is open, thus $q(U)$ is open in $\mathbb RP^n$. Note that $-U = a(U)$, where $a$ is the antipodal map on $S^n$ which is a homeomorphism.

Each of the sets $U_i = \{(x_0,\ldots,x_n) \in S^n  \mid x_i > 0 \}$, $i=0,\ldots,n$, is open in $S^n$ and is mapped by $q$ *bijectively* onto $q(U_i)$. Since $q$ is an open map, $U_i$ is mapped by $q$ *homeomorphically* onto $q(U_i)$. Thus also each subset $E \subset U_i$ is mapped by $q$ homeomorphically onto $q(E)$.

Now let $E^i = \{(x_0,\ldots,x_n) \in S^n  \mid x_i > 0, x_{i+1} = \ldots = x_n = 0 \} \subset U_i$. The $E^i$ are mapped by $q$ homeomorphically onto $A^i = q(E^i)$. Each $E^i$ can be identified with the upper  open half-sphere of the $i$-sphere $S^i \subset \mathbb R^{i+1}$ and is therefore homeomorphic to the open unit ball in $\mathbb R^i$. Thus $A^i  \approx E^i \approx \mathbb R^i$.

The $A^i$ are pairwise disjoint: If $x = (x_0,\ldots,x_n) \in E^i$ and $y = (y_0,\ldots,y_n) \in E^j$ for $i < j$, then $x_j = 0$ and $y_j > 0$, thus $x$ and $y$ are not antipodal and therefore $q(x) \ne q(y)$.

$\bigcup_{i=0}^n A^i = \mathbb RP^n$: Let $y = q(x)$ with $x =(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$. Let $i$ be the biggest index such that $x_i \ne 0$. We may assume that $x_i > 0$, otherwise we replace $x$ by $-x$ which also satisfies $q(-x) = y$. But then we see that $x \in E^i$, i.e. $y \in A^i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the deep explanation! Can you explaine some things that I did not much understand, in the 2nd paragraph why $q^{-1}(q(U))=U\cup(-U)$? , In the 3rd paragraph dis you mean by $R_i$ , $R^{i}$? , In the last paragraph, is that a kind of proof in two sides? Cuz i noticed only one direction..

Comment: (1) $q^{-1}(q(U)) = U \cup (-U)$: $q(U) = \bigcup_{x \in U} \{q(x\})$, thus $q^{-1}(q(U)) = \bigcup_{x \in U} q^{-1}(q(x)) = \bigcup_{x \in U} \{x,-x\} = U \cup (-U)$. (2) It seems $R_i$ confused you. I deleted it because we do not need it. (3) I showed that each point of $\mathbb RP^n$ is contained in $\bigcup_{i=0}^n A_i$. The inclusion $\bigcup_{i=0}^n A_i \subset \mathbb RP^n$ is trivial because all $A_i \subset \mathbb RP^n$.

Comment: What is the accurate definition of $A^{i}/ A_i$?

Comment: I do not understand your question. I wrote $A_i$ instead of $A^i$, and this was defined in my  answer: $A_i = q(E_i)$.

Comment: Okay:), got it!

Comment: I edited my answer to change $A_i$ into $A^i$.