# Union of real spaces

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

I try to show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{RP^n}$.

I can show that $$\mathbb{RP}^n=\mathbb{R}^n\cup\mathbb{R}^{n-1}...\cup\mathbb{R}^1\cup\mathbb{R}^0.$$

But now I have a question. Isn't the union of (for instance) $\mathbb{R}^3\cup\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}^3$? Because the lower dimensional space has to be included in the higher dimensional?
Or can I say that the $\mathbb{R}^2$ has tupel $(x_0,x_1)$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ has tupel $(x_0,x_1,x_2)$  and so they are different and the union is $\{(x_0,x_1),(x_0,x_1,x_2)\}$?

Edit:
Because there is the Question how I show the first equation.
I take a subspace $U_i\subset\mathbb{RP}^n$ with a fixed value for the i-th coordinate. $$U_i=\{(x_0:...:x_{i-1}:x_i=1:x_{i+1}:...:x_n)\}$$ all values of $x_j$ for $j\neq i$ are free, so $U_i$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Now i substract $U_i$ from $\mathbb{RP}^n$.
$$\mathbb{RP}^n\smallsetminus U_i=\{(x_0:...:x_{i-1}:0:x_{i+1}:...:x_n)\}$$ wich is $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$.
It follows that:
$$\mathbb{RP}^n=U_i\cup\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}.$$ I can repeat this until $\mathbb{RP}^0$.
Because $U_i$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n$, I can write $$\mathbb{RP}^n=\mathbb{R}^n\cup\mathbb{R}^{n-1}...\cup\mathbb{R}^1\cup\mathbb{R}^0.$$

Comment: How do you show the union? Note that $\mathbb R^n$ is not really a subset of the projective space. Indeed there is an open set in $\mathbb P^n$ which is identified as $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  In the $n=1$ case you're saying that $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in the unit circle $S^1$.  Well, this depends on how it is embedded.

Comment: I hope that my edit clarifies a bit what I did.
But the important part of my question at the moment is just if $$\mathbb{R}^3\cup\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}^3.$$
Or isn't that true for every situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $\mathbb{RP}^n=\mathbb{R}^n\cup\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\cup...\cup\mathbb{R}^1\cup\mathbb{R}^0$ does not make sense because the $\mathbb R^i$ are certainly **no subsets** of $\mathbb{RP}^n$. But you can write
$$\mathbb{RP}^n = U_n \cup U_{n-1}\cup...\cup U_1\cup U_0$$
where the $U_i$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ which **are homeomorphic** to $\mathbb R^i$. These $U_i$ are pairwise disjoint, thus you never have $U_i \subset U_{i+1}$.

By the way, you should define
$$U_i = \{(x_0: \ldots : x_{i-1}:x_i = 1:x_{i+1}=0: \ldots : x_n=0)\} .$$

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. We are a bit sloppy sometimes and that confuses me.
But I don't understand why I should define $U_i$ like you did?
Because in my case I was able to set $x_i$ to one because of the equivalence relation, but I can't set two values to 1?

Comment: @greeny You are right, you can't. See my edit. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3772057 .